# A function inside a class modifies prototype instead of just returning an object

Tags: livescript

I have this code in LiveScript (1.1.1):

```
class A
  b = -> { a: 1 b: 2 }
```

It compiles into this:

```
var A;
A = (function(){
  A.displayName = 'A';
  var b, prototype = A.prototype, constructor = A;
  b = function(){
    return prototype.a = 1, prototype.b = 2, prototype;
  };
  function A(){}
  return A;
}());
```

Why does b() modify prototype? I expected it to just return a `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this : 
https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/commit/d49b3ee8e8e2d5d7b9f128fa98c210b582e095fe

Which should probably be removed then, mmh.